# Log4j-jul-2.11.2 issue: Log 4j-Jul produced on deployment

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Need a help as I am working on log4j Vulnerability issue. I am working on intellij. I have changed the dependency to point to 2.17.0. However log4j-jul-2.11.2 jar is getting generated.

-rw-r--r--. 1 mdXXX mdpXXX   23998 Jan  8  2021 log4j-jul-2.11.2.jar

This log4j-jul is being picked up from external libraries from Maven. I removed this dependency from library. But its still creating a jar as mentioned above. Any pointers would be helpful.

Adding Pom

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
      
   <spring.integration.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <testng.version>6.8.21</testng.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.4.8</dbunit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <spring.dbunit.version>1.2.0</spring.dbunit.version>
        <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.185</h2.version>
        <ojdbc6.version>11.2.0.2.0</ojdbc6.version>
        <wiremock.version>1.40</wiremock.version>
        <csv.version>1.1</csv.version>
        <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
        <io.version>2.4</io.version>
        <velocity.version>1.7</velocity.version>
        <ucp.version>11.2.0.3</ucp.version>
        <joda.time.version>2.7</joda.time.version>
        <hibernate.entitymanager.version>4.3.9.Final</hibernate.entitymanager.version>
        <hibernate.jpa.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.jpa.version>
        <json.version>2.1-rev7</json.version>

        <surefire.plugin.version>2.18.1</surefire.plugin.version>
        <failsafe.plugin.version>2.18.1</failsafe.plugin.version>
        <compiler.plugin.version>3.3</compiler.plugin.version>
        <assembly.plugin.version>3.0.0</assembly.plugin.version>
        <release.plugin.version>2.3.2</release.plugin.version>
        <pmd.plugin.version>3.8</pmd.plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.plugin.version>2.13</checkstyle.plugin.version>
        <rulesets-directory>build</rulesets-directory>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
                    <!-- *********** -->
            <!-- Spring      -->
            <!-- *********** -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Data  -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Integration     -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- *********** -->
            <!-- Logging     -->
            <!-- *********** -->
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.0</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Try `maven clean` and restart your IDE, this should help you.

Comment: `log4j-jul` is not affected by any vulnerability, but should use the same version as the remaining Log4j 2.x libraries. Can you add your POM file to your question to show how you _"changed the dependency to point to 2.17.0"_? There are several options to do that.

Comment: Thank  you @ZakirHussain i tried but no success

Comment: Thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz added

Answer (score 0):

You must have a transitive dependency on `log4j-jul` and since you didn't specify the version to use in your managed dependencies, Maven chooses `2.11.2`.

Of course, specifying the version of all 26 artifacts of the Log4j 2.x project can be tedious, that is why you can import the [`log4j-bom`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-bom) artifact to do everything faster:

```xml
<properties>
  <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```